# Small language model vocabulary correction

Tags: generative-model, language-model, speech-recognition

I plan to train a small language model (less than 4B parameters) that can run on x86 and handle vocabulary correction such as:

```
in the early days a king rolled the stake
```

which should be corrected to:

```
in the early days a king ruled the state
```

with an update rate of a few words every 1 sec. As in the example, my objective is to fix autocorrection errors and also "sound-alikes", for example from speech recognition errors. I've looked at huggingface.co and e-mailed several lightweight model paper authors, OpenAI, Stability AI, ThirdAI, etc, attempting to locate an existing model but so far no luck.

Is what I'm attempting do-able given the state-of-the-art ? Would I need to limit the vocabulary size and training text / paragraphs (and likewise limit inference input) to achieve this ?